# Send part of an arraylist

Tags: java

I have an `arraylist` in Java that I fill with certain data, but I want to send the array list starting at certain a index say, e.g.: `20`.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail? Send it where for instance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will want to check out the FAQ on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I'm implementing GWT RPC application i want to send part of the arraylist at certain index to the server side to implement some methods on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [subList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method